# Draw text on a shape

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I want to draw a String on some shapes following the examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx and http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image. I use C# , so I need in any case the PaintEventArgs e. However, when I insert it as parameter in a method like DrawStringRectangleF(PaintEventArgs e) it is not (as expected) directly recognized. I import the  System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs and the field “Forms” is still not recognized? What should I do?

Is there any other simpler way to assign text on a shape, the style of which I can adjust?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error or a run time error. If so you what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters, if you are using WinForms you get the graphics object by overriding the OnPaint methods and setting the control styles to manual painting. Like so

```
... .ctor()
{
    ...
    // indicate user will paint
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

    // rest is optional if you want/need it
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);   
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs p)
{
    // depending on how you set the control styles, you might need
    // this to draw the background of your control wit a call to the methods base
    base.OnPaint(p);

    Graphics g = p.Graphics;
    // ... Do your painting here with g ....
}
```

However, since you also tagged this as question as WPF, be warned that this won't work in wpf. I am not very advanced in this subject but I have used overrides of the UIElement.OnRender method and achieved good results. It will give you a DrawingContext object as opposed to a PaintEventArgs object. But they work in much the same way. Plus you won't need to set control styles.

Comment: The problem is potentially that. It does not work in wpf, only in Windows Forms. I need hence to find the implementation of the respective functionality in wpf. Any recommendations accepted.

Comment: How really can the overriding be done? I have not managed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using WPF, just place both your [shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) and your `TextBlock` inside a container that allows controls to overlap, such as a `Grid` or a `Canvas`.

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle ... />
    <TextBlock Text="Test" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```