# Draw text on a shape in a wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

Some of you maybe find this question dull but I am still not deeply accustomed to wpf drawing. I want to add formatted text on a Rectangle which moves around on a canvas and I have got a hint to override the UIElement.OnRender method. However I do not know if I should override the canvas class or the Shape class. In any correct case, to what refers the drawingContext parameter of the method as described in the example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613560.aspx#FormattedText_Object ?

Is the text ultimately assigned to the shape or is it a visual temporary effect that cannot move along with the shape on the canvas?

Is there any further effective means of drawing text on a shape?

Comment: The shapes are created at the runntime of the program, so solutions based on xaml cannot apply to (as far as I know). I need solutions on a dynamic base, namely using C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw text on a shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977240/draw-text-on-a-shape)

Comment: Pretty much all XAML can be easily translated to C#, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw Text on top of a Rectangle by placing both controls in a parent container that allows controls to overlap, such as a `Grid` or a `Canvas`

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" 
               HorizontalAlignement="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Label Content="Test"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

You can then apply whatever formatting you want to the `Label`, the `Rectangle`, and you can move the group around by setting the positioning of the `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

Rachel's answer is correct, although you can extend it a bit, have some UserControl defined as:

And in the codebehind define 1. Label:String DependencyProperty, Shape:UIElement DependencyProperty.

Handle the Shape's change event and call:

```
private void UpdateShape()
{
    grdShapeContainer.Children.Clear();
    if(this.Shape != null)
    {
        grdShapeContainer.Children.Add(this.Shape);
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to make things dynamic.

Regards,
Artak

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into `ZIndex` property which can be set on objects like Grid (`<Rectangle Background="Black" Grid.ZIndex = 99` /> for instance would put it overtop other items) which useful for making things like "loading" screens.