# How do i put some text in Rectangles or have Border around them

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need something like show in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhPCy.png) in wpf canvas using MVVM.

Comment: You should describe your problem accurately, write your efforts and what you have tried so far. Otherwise the question will be closed very quickly

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to learn about basics of control organisation in wpf first,
and you can achieve what you desire using something like this --

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeMoreText" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeMoreText" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="SomeMoreText" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I put it little wrong. I wanted that in canvas. And the rectangles are generated dynamically based on some other collection.

I have achieved drawing rectangles dynamically using ItemControl.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx) for drawing rectangles etc. in WPF.  You can create simple rectangles with labels for the text in XAML too, as shown by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010089/draw-text-on-a-shape-in-a-wpf)

Comment: why not text in border ?

Comment: Yeah, that works too.  Depends on what one is trying to achieve.